# Unable to load the package as XML because of package does not have a valid XML format

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Estoy realizando etls pero he conseguido este error cuando lo ejecuto en el servidor

Executed as user: DOMCOOMEVA\sqlservice. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 12.0.6293.0 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.    Started:  12:34:05 PM  Error: 2020-07-06 12:34:05.61     Code: 0xC0011007     Source: {D9C13D54-C4A8-470A-AC3F-2438FBAF4A8B}      Description: Unable to load the package as XML because of package does not have a valid XML format. A specific XML parser error will be posted.  End Error  Error: 2020-07-06 12:34:05.61     Code: 0xC0011004     Source: {D9C13D54-C4A8-470A-AC3F-2438FBAF4A8B}      Description: Failed to load XML from package file "\pr-cdpwin04\ETLsGSISIN\Conglomerados\ETL_FIDU_STAGE_TO_REPORT.dtsx" due to error 0xC00CE513 "Whitespace is not allowed at this location. Line 921, Column 991".  This occurs when loading a package and the file cannot be opened or loaded correctly into the XML document. This can be the result of specifying an incorrect file name to the LoadPackage method or the specified XML file has an incorrect format.  End Error  Could not load package "\pr-cdpwin04\ETLsGSISIN\Conglomerados\ETL_FIDU_STAGE_TO_REPORT.dtsx" because of error 0xC00CE513.  Description: Failed to load XML from package file "\pr-cdpwin04\ETLsGSISIN\Conglomerados\ETL_FIDU_STAGE_TO_REPORT.dtsx" due to error 0xC00CE513 "Whitespace is not allowed at this location. Line 921, Column 991".  This occurs when loading a package and the file cannot be opened or loaded correctly into the XML document. This can be the result of specifying an incorrect file name to the LoadPackage method or the specified XML file has an incorrect format.  Source: {D9C13D54-C4A8-470A-AC3F-2438FBAF4A8B}  Started:  12:34:05 PM  Finished: 12:34:05 PM  Elapsed:  0.047 seconds.  The package could not be loaded.  The step failed.

¿Saben como resolvero?

Comment: Hi there. This is [es.so]. Please translate your question to spanish. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Tu pregunta debes formularla en castellano, de lo contrario terminará cerrada. Saludos

Comment: A priori el error indica que tienes un espacio en blanco en la linea 921 columna 991. Y eso no encaja en el formato xml. Revisa esa fila y esa columna del origen de datos.